# Putty Loading Previous instance Even though i load right .ppk file

Tags: ssh, centos, putty, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to Google cloud centos terminal using External IP Address and .ppk file but putty is taking previous loaded IP Address from AWS centos terminal and I loaded right .ppk file

Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not comprehensible. What do you mean by *"putty is taking previous loaded IP Address from AWS centos terminal"*? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I connected to AWS instance by using .ppk file and after that i created the instance in GCP and i am trying to connect to GCP instance using .ppk file but it is still taking the AWS instance

Comment: Are you connecting to a hostname or an IP address?

Comment: Yes i am connecting to Hostname and i took hostname from GCP External IP address but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by deleting History of putty by using below command from command prompt

***Putty.exe --clean***